# Connecting ELM 327 to Android (bluetooth)- Getting UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth, elm327

i got the following code from the internet

```
try {
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(bdDevice.toString());

    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    socket.connect();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"socket bonded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch(Exception e) {
    tv.setText(e.toString());
}
```

of course the uuid is a random code just for example, so how do i get the desired uuid ? should it be the uuid of my ELM327 device or another uuid? excuse me i am new to the uuid thing and android development.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which GATT Profile and Services are used by OBD BLE Adapters like LELink, Automatic, Carista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075456/which-gatt-profile-and-services-are-used-by-obd-ble-adapters-like-lelink-automa)

Answer (score 1):

The UUID in this case isn't "random code" but the identifying key for the Bluetooth serial port service profile.

Answer (score 1):

i just checked the UUID i used in a previous project and it is the same .
i used it like this

```
try {
        mSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        mSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

it was working perfectly when i developed the App.

but ELM327 device available in the market was problematic.some times in pairing.

perhaps you should use getAddress() function instead of bdDevice.toString()

**getAddress** will give the mac which will be unique to the device .

```
 public String getAddress ()
   Added in API level 5

   Returns the hardware address of this BluetoothDevice.

   For example, "00:11:22:AA:BB:CC".
```

**getRemoteDevice** expects a device address

```
  getRemoteDevice(byte[] address)
   Get a BluetoothDevice object for the given Bluetooth hardware address.
```