# How to send “AT” commands over Ionic(Angular)?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic-native, obd-ii

I would like to program an app where I can read live data from an ODB2 ELM327 BLE connector. For this use the BluetoothLE plugin. I already get a connection, but I don’t know where and how to send my “AT” command to get live data.

1. On which service and characteristic do I have to send the command?
2. Do I need to send the command with write?
3. What should the command look like (hexadecimal, etc)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which GATT Profile and Services are used by OBD BLE Adapters like LELink, Automatic, Carista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075456/which-gatt-profile-and-services-are-used-by-obd-ble-adapters-like-lelink-automa)